# Manual calculation of randomForest() residuals

Tags: r, random-forest

It seems for me that procedure of prediction with random forest in regression case is non-trivial, as I obtain different result then built-in procedure :

```
set.seed(1)
wyn <- randomForest(y = iris[, 1], x = iris[, -1])
(wyn) #Mean of squared residuals: 0.1341068

response=predict(wyn, iris[, -1]) # is it ok ? below to lines gives different output

mean((iris[,1]-wyn$predicted)^2) #returns 0.1341068
mean((iris[,1]-response)^2) # returns 0.07259335


plot(wyn$predicted,response) # almost but not identical
```

what's wrong with my use of `predict()` above ?

Answer (score 1):

ok, now I know :

```
#returns out-of-bag error
mean((iris[,1]-wyn$predicted)^2) #returns 0.1341068 

#returns error calculated on whole dataset
mean((iris[,1]-response)^2) # returns 0.07259335
```